# Resolving dependencies from external files

Tags: c, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

i'm new in azure devops pipeline. 
I have three C project in Azure Repos Git and I've configured a linux self-hosted agents.

The C_project_3 depends from .h and .a files of C_project_2 which in turn depends on .h and .a files of C_project_1.

The C_project_1 needs to build a not versioned file stored on the agent.

Is it possible configure the YAML file, of each project, to start the building process on cascade resolving the dependencies of .h, .a and extern file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution for question "***The C_project_1 needs to build a not versioned file stored on the agent***"

The sources of project are loaded on the agent in folder _work/1/s.
The not versioned file must be stored there.

I found the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops

In detail:

> **Single repository:** Your source code is checked out into a directory called s located as a subfolder of (Agent.BuildDirectory).
>   If (Agent.BuildDirectory) is C:\agent_work\1 then your code is
>   checked out to C:\agent_work\1\s.

Comment: I have found the solution also at first question: use "checkout" command to clone the code into the agent.